# OrderBy child collection specific category

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following sample classes.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
}
```

and the following sample data.

```
var parents = new List<Parent>()
{
    new Parent() {
        Id = 1,
        Children = new List<Child>
        {
            new Child {Category = "Item 1", Price = 10 },
            new Child {Category = "Item 2", Price = 30 },
            new Child {Category = "Item 3", Price = null },
            new Child {Category = "Item 4", Price = 5 },
            new Child {Category = "Item 5", Price = 20 }
        }
    },
    new Parent() {
        Id = 2,
        Children = new List<Child>
        {
            new Child {Category = "Item 1", Price = null },
            new Child {Category = "Item 2", Price = null },
            new Child {Category = "Item 3", Price = null },
            new Child {Category = "Item 4", Price = null },
            new Child {Category = "Item 5", Price = null }
        }
    },
    new Parent() {
        Id = 3,
        Children = new List<Child>
        {
            new Child {Category = "Item 1", Price = 100 },
            new Child {Category = "Item 2", Price = 300 },
            new Child {Category = "Item 3", Price = null },
            new Child {Category = "Item 4", Price = 50 },
            new Child {Category = "Item 5", Price = 200 }
        }
    },
};
```

How can I use LINQ to order `Parent` objects by `Child`'s price with specific category, say "Item 3"?

Comment: You mean something like this? parents.OrderBy(x => x.Children.Where(y => y.Category == "Item 3").Max(z => z.Price));

Comment: That did it, thanks. Feel free to post as answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
parents.OrderBy(x => x.Children.Where(y => y.Category == "Item 3").Max(z => z.Price));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var resultSet = parents.OrderBy(o => o.Children.Where(e => e.Category == "Item 3").Max(i => i.Price)).ToList();
```

Comment: I believe he is asking about sorting the Parents based on the Children's property, but this will give him a list of Children.

Comment: @FredyTreboux edited it to return a list of Parents instead.

Comment: Thanks for this. But without `Min()` or `Max()` I get `At least one object must implement IComparable.` exception.